# Can sum of two vectors be scalar

Tags: vectors

Can coordinates be seen as Euclidean vectors, because if they can be seen like that then, in the unit circle by which we define functions like sine, cosine etc. Can we say that sum of two vectors can be a "scalar" quantity?? Which in this case is the radius of the unit circle. In general, can sum of two vectors be just a scalar?

Sorry, I might just be mixing up things. I just want to know what I am saying is right or not and if not where I messed up. Thanks.

Comment: Zero vector is not scalar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, in general you cannot consider a sum of two vectors as a scalar. The only sum defined on vectors has a vector as result, and vectors are different from scalars.

If the vector space is a dimension 1 space on itself, for example $\mathbb{R}$ considered as a vector space upon itself, it might look as if vectors and scalars are the same thing, but that's a particular case. In any case it is necessary to keep them as separate entities because they do not have the same properties, e.g. when changing the base, scalars are not affected.

Answer (score 1):

Things would be clearer if we view the definition of vector sum directly:

> The first operation, called vector addition or simply addition assigns to any two vectors $\mathbf{v}$ and $\mathbf{w}$ in $V$ a third vector in $V$ which is commonly written as $\mathbf{v} + \mathbf{w}$, and called the sum of these two vectors. (excerpted from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space#Definition_and_basic_properties))

So by definition, sum of two vectors is still a vector.

Now another thing that we still need to consider is that is it possible that sum of two vectors is both a vector and a scalar? An affirmative answer are already given by Jean-Armand Moroni.
But in general, sum of vectors would not be a scalar.
This is because it is very difficult to define multiplication/division of vectors without breaking some very nice properties that scalars would have, such as every non-zero scalar would have a multiplicative inverse.